# js:using dateformat with google geochart(getformattedValue)?

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization

I want to get value from the table in google sheet with the format

> January 2008 [%M %Y]

now I have the javascript code to get the value like this(this is the code for display tooltips text in google geochart)

```js
var country = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 9)
var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 10)
var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)

return '<div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '</div> ' +
  '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:</div>' +
  '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '</div>' +
  '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + '</div>' +
  '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '</div>'
```

I want variable **startdate** to display date in format full month and full year
but I don't know how to use dateformat with this dt.getFormattedValue(row, 10)

EDITED

**the date in the sheet is like 13-Dec-2008
and I 've read [this document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter) from google and tried this code

```js
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: "MMMM, yyyy,"
});
formatter.format(dt, 10);
//var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 10)


return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
  '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
  '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
  '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + formatter + '</div><br><br><br>' +
  '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
```

but still doesn't work,the tooltips text still get the date like 13-Dec-2008

thanks

Comment: use Moment.js, if using external libraries is not a restriction -
 https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
  `moment(startdate).format('MMMM YYYY'); `

Comment: give example date of google sheet date

Comment: @JYoThI the date in the sheet is like 13-Dec-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `format` function formats the entire data table column
this should be used before drawing the chart

to format a single value, use the `formatValue` function

see following snippet...

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: "MMMM, yyyy,"
});
var startdate = formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 10));


return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
  '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
  '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
  '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + '</div><br><br><br>' +
  '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
```